# Camera phone check depositing risks

Tags: united-states, deposits, check

What risks are there in using a camera phone to deposit checks that are given to me?

To clarify: my risks.

To clarify: checks given to me.

Comment: For the paranoid, the risk is how many entities other than the bank will spy on the transaction.  Especially if they have Android.  But then again, the paranoid wouldn't have a phone programmed by NSA's biggest competitor.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only risk for you is that you may accidentally present a check twice, particularly if you cash a lot of checks for similar amounts. For example, I was a treasurer of a club, and probably received about 30 checks for $25 every few months. Eventually, they all start looking the same!

My bank advises that I write "Check Electronically Presented" on the face of the check and retain it until I receive a statement showing the deposit. So if you follow that advice, make sure you keep those checks in a different location!

Comment: Should not the bank that is cashing, should look for if the check is presented earlier ? Why this responsibility falls on customer and not the bank ?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the bank's application is sending the data encrypted, and not leaving a picture of the check on the phone, then the risk is minimal.

If the pictures remain on the phone, then someone who steals/finds that phone would have routing and account number information present in those images.

Also a question of that happens to the original check, since it has that same info on it.

Of course if someone has your check in their wallet and gets robbed before they can deposit it, the same risk is there.

If you are really paranoid, you could always ask them to do the 'deposit' right as you give them the check, and then dispose of it afterwards.

Comment: thanks these are great answers but none of these actually sound like risks to me (well other than someone stealing my phone) These sound like they are all risks to the person who gave me the check.

Comment: @JustinOhms You didn't ask for only the risks to you.  Maybe you could edit your question to clarify?